# C# lottery 6 from 49 algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to display odds to win with ten decimals if I play with just one variant, for six five and four numbers. For example I need to have this 0.0000000715 but I have this 0.0027829314 if I introduce 49,6,I. What is the problem?How can I make it work? I am a beginner and I don't know how i can obtain this 0.0000000715.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string category = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (category)
        {
            case "I":
                calculate(n,k);
                break;
            case "II":
                calculate(n, k);
                break;
            case "III":
                calculate(n, k);
                break;
        }
    }
    static void calculate(int n, int k)
    {
        int nk = n - k;
       decimal count = prod(1, nk) / prod(k + 1, n);
        decimal r = prod(1, k) / prod(n - k + 1, n);
        decimal sum = count * r;
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(r,10));
    }

    static decimal prod(int x, int y)
    {
        decimal prod = 0;
        for(int i = x; i <= y; i++)
        {
            prod = x * y;
        }
        return prod;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your prod function is probably not doing what you want. The loop is useless, because the result is overwritten every time and not reused.

Comment: I want to know how to fix it to have this result 0.0000000715 instead of this  0.0027829314? I understand the prod it's useless but i don't know how to make it to work @jjj

Comment: What exactly is prod supposed to do? Without knowing this, I could only post a totally unrelated code that leads to the correct result, that is not based on yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution would be `bc(6,n)*bc(49-6,6-n)/bc(49, 6)`, where n is, 4, 5 or 6 and bc is the binomial coefficient.

Btw.: double should be enough for 10 decimal places, there is no need to use decimal.

```
using System;       
public class Program
{
    //bonomial coefficient
    static double bc(double n, double k)  
    {
        if (k == 0 || k == n) 
            return 1;
        return bc(n - 1, k - 1) + bc(n - 1, k); 
    } 
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int n = 4; n <=6; ++n){
            Console.WriteLine(bc(6,n)*bc(49-6,6-n)/bc(49, 6));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sur what function you were using.

The chances of winning all 6 numbers is 1 in 13,983,816

The actual calculation is this:

49C6 = 49!/(43! x 6!) = 13983816

So the probability to win is 1 / 13,983,816 = 0.0000000715

Comment: I try this solution but solution is 0.9716169748. I don't know where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your prod function should look like:

```
 static decimal prod(int x, int y)
    {
        decimal prod = 1;
        for(int i = x; i <= y; i++)
        {
            prod = prod * i;
        }
        return prod;
    }
```

Comment: If prod is factorial this would lead to really big numbers, you have to be really careful about the possible range of the datatype and its percision, the numbers are too large for decimal.

Answer (score -1):

As jjj mentioned, you overwrite "prod" everytime, but you need to add it

Comment: How can I make ? I am a beginner  and I don't understand the way to do this? @Guest

Comment: It is correct but this message does not qualify as an answer,it is preferable to add a comment in the original question.

Comment: @PascalGanaye you can add it by using += instead of =, but this will not lead the the right result.