# Winning lottery odds

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, probability

I have another question about lottery. I have to make this problem: "You want to participate in the game of chance 6 out of 49 with only one variant and you want to know what chances you will win:category I (6 numbers),category II (5 numbers),category III (4 numbers). Write a application that receive as input data the total number of balls, the number of balls drawn and then prints the chances of winning with an accuracy of 10 decimals if played with a single variant". My question is: What is the formula to calculate this?I try to find that formula but i didn't find it. An example will be 40, 5 and II (5 numbers) and the result is 0.0002659542 or 45 , 15 and category III is 0.0000001324.I need to mention i am a beginner. My code is working but just for 6 from 49.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string extract = Console.ReadLine();
        int category1 = category(extract);
        switch (category1)
        {
            case 6:
                calculateTheOddsToWin(n, k, extract);
                break;
            case 5:
                calculateTheOddsToWin(n, k, extract);
                break;
            case 4:
                calculateTheOddsToWin(n, k, extract);
                break;
        }

    }
        static void calculateTheOddsToWin(int n , int k , string extract)
    {
        double comb = combination(n, k);
        decimal solution =(decimal)( 1 / comb);
        decimal round = Math.Round(solution,10);
        Console.WriteLine(round);
    }
        static double combination(int n, int k)
        {
            double factN = factorialN(n);
            double factK = factorialK(k);
            double factNK = substractFactorialNK(n, k);
            double combination = factN / (factNK * factK);
            return combination;
        }

        static double factorialN(int n)
        {
            double factorialN = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                factorialN *= i;
            }
            return factorialN;
        }
        static double factorialK( int k)
        {
            double factorialK = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            {
                factorialK *= i;
            }
            return factorialK;
        }
        static double substractFactorialNK(int n, int k)
        {
            double factorialNK = 1;
            int substract = n - k;
            for (int i = 1; i <= substract; i++)
            {
                factorialNK *= i;
            }
            return factorialNK;
        }
        static int category(string extract)
        {
           if(extract == "I")
            {
                return 6;
            }else if(extract == "II")
            {
                return 5;
            }else if(extract == "III")
            {
                return 4;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: FYI your factorialN and factorialK are identical, you can just replace them with a single "factorial" method

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i make this improvement. ty

Comment: there was the same question for java a few days ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104134/c-sharp-lottery-6-from-49-algorithm/

Comment: Factorial grows so fast and high, that you cant store it in an `int`. `int` typically is between -2 147 483 648 and 2 147 483 647.

Comment: it's not working for 40,5, and category II my result for that 0.0000531474 and i need this result 0.0002659542 @jjj . I actually put in a double because in that way can store a big number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# lottery 6 from 49 algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104134/c-sharp-lottery-6-from-49-algorithm)

Comment: You need to do calculation of binomial coefficient without factorial. Btw.: Why do you use factorialK and factorialN? the do exactly the same, renaming an internal valiable doent change anything

Comment: I improve that now is just factorialN

Comment: it's not working for 40,5 and II or something else like 35 6 III

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218992/discussion-between-darkmaster-and-jjj).

Comment: Look up the mathematical concept of *Combinations". You should also think about how lottery drawings work. If there are 49 balls bouncing in the drum, and you pull one out, you have a one in 49 chance of guessing correctly. But now there are 48 balls left. So if you pull one out, you have a one in 48 chance of getting it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate three numbers:

```
T: The total number of combinations
W: The number of ways to draw the desired amount of winning numbers
L: The number of ways to draw the desired amount of losing numbers
Then, the answer is W * L / T
```

Example: 40 numbers, 5 draws, 4 correct:

```
W = choose(5,4) = 5 (4 winners from 5 possibilities)
L = choose(35,1) = 35 (1 loser from 35 possibilities)
T = choose(40, 5) = 658008 (5 numbers from 40 possibilities)

5 * 35 / 658008 = 0.00265954
```

Generically:

```
n = count of numbers
d = count of available winning numbers = draw size
k = count of winning numbers drawn (d, d-1, and d-2 for I, II, III).
W = choose(d, k) (k winners from d possibilities)
L = choose(n-d, d-k) (d-k losers from n-d possibilities)
T = choose(n, d) (d numbers from n possibilities)
```

Comment: Why W is(5 and 4) because i enter from keyboard 40,5 and category II (5 numbers not 4)? and why 1 at L ?

Comment: There are 40 numbers, 5 of which are winners. In the example we need 4 winning numbers and 1 losing numbers. The 4 winning numbers are chosen from the 5 available winning numbers. The 1 losing number is chosen from the 40-5=35 available losing numbers.

Comment: ty this was very useful but if i have 45,15 and III the code is not working properly.

Comment: 45, 15, III: choose(15, 13) * choose(30, 2) / choose(45, 15) = 0.000000132442